# *Solved* A visualization showing new records, closed records and total open records for each month

Tags: date, datetime, count, tableau-api, counting

My data comes as a list of records where each row represents an individual task.  Each task has a date it is created and a date that it is closed along with misc task details.

I want to visualize, preferably in one sheet, this data for a year showing each month the total new tasks, total closed tasks, and total open tasks (which includes tasks open from before the date range of the visualization).

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this without some data massaging.

I don't have the reputation to post images but I'm trying to replicate a chart like https://i.stack.imgur.com/kufxd.jpg.

My sample data and poor attempts at visualization are found @ https://public.tableau.com/profile/matthew4846#!/vizhome/OpenClosedSample/Sheet2

Does anyone have a way to make the visualization I want from the data I have?

Comment: is the issue solved?

Comment: Yes it has been.  I can't mark it as solved since I responded to my own comment.  I'll edit the title.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has been resolved by looking at "Ticket Counting" posts as suggested by Zach Leber over at the Tableau forums.

https://community.tableau.com/message/907768#907768